Moodle open question
Good morning, I need to write a problem in LaTeX using the moodle package that includes a question and an open answer (in which the student can write his answer). At the same time, the correct answer (the explanation of how the exercise is carried out) must appear at the end of the exercise. Someone can help me? I try with description (but It don't work)
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[section]{moodle}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{quiz}{Problema}{ \begin{essay}{}{Si consideri la funzione [f(x)=(x\tan x)^2] a) se ne determini il dominio
b) si calcoli la derivata prima \ c) si calcoli la derivata seconda} \item[feedback={La funzione assegnata `e non negativa ed essendo: .... RISOLUZIONE PROBLEMA] }] 
\end{essay} 
\end{quiz} 
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Without seeing any code from you it is hard to help you. What do you mean with it dont work? Got you error messages? Which one? Have you asked your local moodle support?

The Moodle package documentation has useful information, maybe you can point out an example from there that you want to extend, and for which you point out what is still missing for your use case.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

@Marijin I just read the package but I don't found an answer for my problem (probably there is...but I can't see it). I write also to the author of packega for his help..

You are mixing several things here... the essay is a free text problem, so if you want items you must use an itemize environment, and the option for the feedback must be given to the essay environment, not to the \item command.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[section]{moodle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{quiz}{Problema}
    \begin{essay}[feedback={La funzione assegnata è non negativa ed essendo: .... RISOLUZIONE PROBLEMA}]{Tangenti}
    Si consideri la funzione $f(x)=(x\tan x)^2$
    \begin{itemize}
        \item se ne determini il dominio
        \item si calcoli la derivata prima
        \item si calcoli la derivata seconda
    \end{itemize}
    \end{essay}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}


By the way, if you want to use the Moodle package, make a favor to you and use lualatex or xelatex and input accented characters (like è) directly. I think this is also commented on in the manual.

Thank you very much, It run but I have another problem, now. The sentences in the answer do not wrap correctly...

Hi, please ask another question with a minimal example. Remember that the PDF output is only informational, you should check the question in Moodle.
